# How to use two lists in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the awesome framework angular js. I'm facing a tiny problem.

I'm using two lists I'm not really sure if we can do something similar to this

```
ng-repeat ="player1 in team1 | orderBy:'id'"
```

and then

```
<h3>{{player1.name}} - {{player2.name}}</h3>
```

my json looks like :

```
{
"team1":[
{
"name":"player1T1",
"id":"1",
"role":"goalkeeper"
},
{
"name":"player2T1",
"id":"3",
"role":"attacker"
},
  {
"name":"player3T1",
"id":"2",
"role":"midfielder"
},

],
"team2":[

{
"name":"player2T2",
"id":"3",
"role":"attacker"
},
  {
"name":"player3T2",
"id":"2",
"role":"midfielder"
},
{
"name":"player1T2",
"id":"1",
"role":"goalkeeper"
}
]
}
```

I want to show something similar to this :

```
Player1T1 (goalkeeper) - Player1T2 (goalkeeper) 
Player2T1 (attacker)   - Player2T2 (attacker)
Player3T1 (midfielder) - Player3T2 (midfielder)
```

Thanks for giving me the answer to the first problem, and in the same time i'm using order by how can I order the second team as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not going each vs each, but in pairs, this will work:

```
<h3>{{team1[$index].name}} - {{team2[$index].name}}</h3>
```

And since there is the equal number of players in each team, a single ng-repeat will work (just to get the $index):

```
ng-repeat ="player1 in team1"
```

---

See it here:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.teams = {
    "team1": [{
      "name": "player1",
      "id": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "player2",
      "id": "2"
    }],
    "team2": [{
      "name": "player4",
      "id": "4"
    }, {
      "name": "player3",
      "id": "3"
    }]
  }
  
  function sortById(a,b){return a.id > b.id}
  
  $scope.teams.team1.sort(sortById);
  $scope.teams.team2.sort(sortById);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in teams.team1">
    <h3>{{teams.team1[$index].name}} - {{teams.team2[$index].name}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Hmmm, the best idea would to restructure your object so that you can get clear data and order. Maybe something like `matches = [[p1, p3], [p2, p4]]` and then do `ng-repeat` on `matches`. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm thinking of ordering the lists on the controller, is ther any thing like " Order by " I can use ?

Comment: You could, but I don't see anything you can use to order by. I'd make that matches object (on the controller as well) by iterating of the teams. It will give you less headache in the future.

Comment: Can you suggest an example please ?

Comment: Sure, just give me something so I'd know how you select the pairs.

Comment: Oh, I see, you can use `track by` (`ng-repeat="x in obj track by x.someProperty"`) but it will get complicated. You better modify your teams object (or simply sort them by id, as you suggested) or create a new one, so that it is clear who plays against whom.

Comment: Updated my example with a custom sortById function that sorts both teams.

Comment: Frankly, everyone coming here for 'How to use two lists in ng-repeat Angular' will not find a solution. You could improve your answer with that solution and then have your current answer as a "but what you really want is probably ...".

Comment: @Jeppe Generally, you'd still need to find a common factor between the lists and then use that to iterate over the combined items. No answer could really cover everything here because the question sounds way too generic, so maybe making the question titles more specific is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine your teams into one array. Doing that would allow for variable numbers of teams and players.

```
var allPlayers= [];
for(var prop in teams){
     teams[prop].forEach(function(player){
          player['team'] = prop;
          allPlayers.push(player);
     });
}
```

Then bind to the `allPlayers` array in your HTML